# Insert a blank row above , "True" which is in column "T"

Tags: excel, vba, row, addition, excel-365

I have a worksheet, which is populated from another sheet, which can have a variable amount of rows.
In this worksheet I am trying to insert a blank row above , "True" which is in column "T".
In that  Blank row in column D I want to add ">JOBSTART"

Then I want to add another blank row, above all " >JOBSTART" except WHEN IT IS IN "D2".
In that  Blank row in column D I want to add ">JOBEND".
The last row would also have ">JOBEND".
I have tried multiple VBA's but nothing gives me the result I'm looking for.

I tried this but it just adds a blank row at the bottom of my list.

```
Sub InsertOneRowAboveBlankCells()

Dim sColBlnk As Range, ar As Range
Set sColBlnk = Range("s:s").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
For Each ar In sColBlnk.Areas
ar.Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Insert
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
Sub InsertRow()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ' Set the worksheet object
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")   ' modify accrodingly

    ' insert row if value "True"
    For i = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "T").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
        If ws.Cells(i, "T").Value = "True" Then
            ws.Rows(i).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        End If
    Next i
    
    'enter jobstart for each blank rows
    For i = 2 To ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
        If ws.Cells(i, "D").Value = "" Then
            ws.Cells(i, "D").Value = ">JOBSTART"
        End If
    Next i

    ' insert row if value jobstart
    For i = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row To 3 Step -1
        If ws.Cells(i, "D").Value = ">JOBSTART" Then
            ws.Rows(i).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        End If
    Next i

    'enter jobend for each blank rows
    For i = 3 To ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
        If ws.Cells(i, "D").Value = "" Then
            ws.Cells(i, "D").Value = ">JOBEND"
        End If
    Next i

    ' Add ">JOBEND" to the last row in column D
    ws.Cells(ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1, "D").Value = ">JOBEND"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```